# Why is my Sqlite table doubling it's self?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

My Sqlite table should have 50 rows. When I run the program for the first time, and go to check the table through firefox viewer, I see 50 rows (as it should be).

When I run the program for a second time and check the table, it's rows double - i,e it now has 100 rows. **(This is the problem)**

Ive had suggestions to use DELETE from, but I dont want to delete the table, as I want to see it in the firefox viewer after I run the program for debugging purposes.

```
 // We use these three SQLite objects:
          SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
          SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;

          // create a new database connection: 
          sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=database.db;Version=3;");

          // open the connection:
          sqlite_conn.Open();

          // create a new SQL command:
          sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

          // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tab1' (Seq text, Field text, Desc text, Len text, Dec text, Typ text, Percnt text, Pop text, Alzero text, MaxLen text );";

          // Now lets execute the SQL                                                                                 
          sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          // **** SQLITE TRANSFER SECTION 1 - transfer values from list to table *****

          sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tab1 (Seq, Field, Desc, Len, Dec, Typ, Percnt, Pop, Alzero, MaxLen) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10)";
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 6);  // dummy initial values 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 878); 
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 56);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", 6);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", 546);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", 565);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", 568);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", 526);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", 586);
          sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", 526);


          for (int i = 0; i < NumListValues; i += 10) // Filling SQlite table rows and columns with values from our list 
          {

              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", list[i]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", list[i+1]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", list[i+2]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", list[i+3]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", list[i+4]);
              if (i > 490)
                  break; 
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", list[i+5]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", list[i+6]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", list[i+7]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", list[i+8]);
              sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", list[i+9]);
              sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          }
```

Comment: do you check anywhere if the table already contains your rows on the second startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run the program for a second time and check the table, it's rows double - i,e it now has 100 rows.

Well yes, it would. You've said to create the table *if it doesn't exist*, and then you're inserting a bunch of data, without removing what was already there.

It won't actually double each time - it'll just add `NumListValues / 10` rows every time you run it, because that's what you've said you want to do.

If you want to delete any existing rows from the table before you start inserting (i.e. at the *start* of the run rather than at the end) then you'll need to do so explicitly. You could either use `TRUNCATE TABLE` or `DELETE FROM ...`.

Comment: I tried implementing DELETE FROM statement before the insert statement and it works like a charm, thanks. @Jon Skeet

I have another problem but havent got any relevant replies yet.. can you pls check it out when you have time
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776254/not-all-specified-contents-from-txt-file-are-getting-transferred-to-sqlite-db?noredirect=1#comment29409382_19776254

Answer (score 1):

Your script create the table the first time you call it, and it inserts records.

The second time you call it, you are not recreating the table, because you have use the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` clause. BUT, you are still inserting records to the table!

If you call your script a third time, you will have 150 rows.